# Мультирегистрация для сайта на Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, форма, регистрация

Как можно самому или при помощи плагинов создать форму регистрации типа "зарегистрироваться как учитель" и "зарегистрироваться как студент" на одном сайте?

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21655577/multiple-user-registration-forms-for-different-types-of-users-in-wordpress
Тут пишут что Profile Builder позволяет с помощью шорткодов создавать множетственные формы регистрации для различных типов юзеров.
https://www.cozmoslabs.com/wordpress-profile-builder тут сам модуль
https://www.cozmoslabs.com/28983-multiple-user-registration-forms/ тут пошаговая инструкция.
Надеюсь поможет.